# Meteor pairing two clients

Tags: meteor

I am currently programing a game (just to learn Meteor) and I am wondering, how to pair two clients, so that they can send information rather directly (and simple).

I "only" want to pass Objects between the two clients, which aren't meant to stay in a DB. (I worked with websockets before. Maybe there is something like that in meteor?)

Comment: So, how to allow two web clients to communicate to each other directly? I can think of [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebRTC), which has nothing to do with Meteor since it's a native API. Also, the [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebSockets) are in Meteor, because Meteor is built on top of Node and so you can use all Node features with it. The issues with your question are all the noise ("I have a problem", "thanks", "I'm a noob", "[edit]"...), asking for a library (off-topic!) and its very broad scope. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: @Kyll better? (I just wanted to be nice, and the edit was just because I am used to it (from another forum)). But thanks for the notes!

Comment: Yep, thank you for your attention (and trying to be nice, it's extremely important too! =p). In the end you have to consider your question as it would be read two or three years from now, so you should try to make as timeless as possible (when applicable, updates to follow new versions or implementations are fine).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but since you mention you are doing this to learn Meteor, I would approach this in a typical Meteor fashion, and not open up other sockets for direct communication between two clients. Meteor already comes with websockets communication between server and clients, called DDP. Rather than connecting two clients directly, why don't you let them communicate with each other via the server?

You don't need to store the object in a collection to take advantage of reactivity. A typical meteor approach would be to declare a reactive variable on the server, let client A update the variable, and client B subscribes to the variable. Everytime the variable changes, all subscribed clients get notified and can react. I would consider it a bonus that the server is in the loop of what's being sent back and forth.

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind, I just wasn't really clear of how to "set it up". With the keywords, it should be pretty simple to find the code! Thanks alot! (I just mentioned the websocets, in case there is something like that, but this also works)

Answer (score 0):

If permanent datastore is not a requirement then maybe these packages will come to help. You need server though. Serverless solution can be achieved with WebRTC but that needs some set up (signaling server, etc...)

[mkarliner:mqtt](https://atmospherejs.com/mkarliner/mqtt)

[joncursi:socket-io-client](https://atmospherejs.com/joncursi/socket-io-client)